# Add new Wordpress page with preselected parent

Tags: wordpress

I do not want my clients to select a parent page from the drop down list, when creating a child page in Wordpres, so I would like to now if there is a way to create a link on the dashboard which links to "add new page" - but with a preselected parent page?

If this is not possible, then is there a way to change the default parent from "(no parent)" to a parent of my choice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this script in your plugins folder and it'll give new pages a parent of whatever you set as `$parent_id`

```
<?php
    function set_parent($content) {
        /* >> Begin user-configurable variable >> */
        $parent_id = '1'; // ID for parent page >> */
        /* >> End user-configurable variable >> */
        $pattern = "option value='{$parent_id }'";
        $replace = "option value='{$parent_id }' selected=\"selected\"";
        $content = str_replace($pattern, $replace, $content);
    return $content;
    }

if( strstr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'wp-admin/post-new.php?post_type=page') ) {
ob_start('set_parent');
}
?>
```

That should do what you want. And I suppose you could add a dropdown option in somewhere to select parents if a set default parent isn't sufficient like in this example.

Comment: thank you very much for your reply. Unfortunately your script does not work for me, for some reason. I have added it as a plugin and activated it, but the parent is not selected when I add a new page. 

I am using WP 3.3.2

Comment: Right sorry, something must of changed in recent versions. I was trying to avoid telling you to change core code. I'll try and find another method.

Comment: ah okay. Thank you, would be amazing if you can figure out how to fix it :)

Comment: Did you find out if this is possible, or should I try to find another solution? :)

Comment: No, sorry. I suggest you ask on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ where you'll certainly find more help :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a tough question to answer sticking with core wordpress ideas. Would you normally have more than one parent page available?

Do you think that about a different way for your client to manage page structure would work?

Admin Column View Plugin is great and allows the user to use drag and drop to reorder pages - http://wordpress.org/plugins/admin-column-view/screenshots/

Hope this helps.